# How Can I use JSON?

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON file:

```
[{"Vorname":"VName 0","Nachname":"Nname 0","Personalnummer":"PN- 0","Rolle ":"Dozent"},{"Vorname":"VName 1","Nachname":"Nname 1","Personalnummer":"PN- 1","Rolle":"Student"},{"Vorname":"VName 2","Nachname":"Nname 2","Personalnummer":"PN- 2","Rolle ":"Dozent"},{"Vorname":"VName 3","Nachname":"Nname 3","Personalnummer":"PN- 3","Rolle":"Student"},{"Vorname":"VName 4","Nachname":"Nname 4","Personalnummer":"PN- 4","Rolle ":"Dozent"},{"Vorname":"VName 5","Nachname":"Nname 5","Personalnummer":"PN- 5","Rolle":"Student"},{"Vorname":"VName 6","Nachname":"Nname 6","Personalnummer":"PN- 6","Rolle ":"Dozent"},{"Vorname":"VName 7","Nachname":"Nname 7","Personalnummer":"PN- 7","Rolle":"Student"},{"Vorname":"VName 8","Nachname":"Nname 8","Personalnummer":"PN- 8","Rolle ":"Dozent"},{"Vorname":"VName 9","Nachname":"Nname 9","Personalnummer":"PN- 9","Rolle":"Student"},{"Vorname":"VName 10","Nachname":"Nname 10","Personalnummer":"PN- 10","Rolle ":"Dozent"}]
```

--> Filename myfile.json

Now I have include the file with

```
$json = file_get_contents('/adress/myfile.json');
$data = json_decode($json);
```

If I work with
echo $jason, i see the complete file.

Now I want to get the variable

Like

```
$firstname[0]=$vorname[0];
```

--> Vorname is the variable in the JSON file
--> firstname is the variable in the active file

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The content is stored under `$data`, so you have to start from there:

```
$data[0]->Vorname
```

If you want to use associative arrays instead, use `json_decode($json, true);`:

```
$data[0]['Vorname']
```

Comment: U are perfect!!! Thanks...